# How do I use terminal in VSCode for running java code when object of different file make in the different file but both file lie in same package?

Tags: java, object, visual-studio-code

How do I use terminal in VSCode for running java code when object of different file make in the different file but both file lie in same package?

I was trying to run my code in particular file in which contain an object of other file in terminal in VSCode using these steps:

1. cd Package name
2. javac ParticularClass.java OtherClass.java
3. java ParticularClass.java

And an error comes: `other class file not found`.
Please tell me how to use terminal manually in case of object oriented programing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.